# QList of Custom Objects

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I am trying to create a `QList` of custom objects, but am unable to do so.  The compilation error I receive when trying to do so is:

`error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (file not found)`

I am able to create a `QList` of pointers of custom objects, as well as that of primitive data types.  I know `QList` supports doing what I am trying to do, as it says so in the documentation.

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5, Qt 5.0.1, and Qt Creator 2.6.2.

Code:

```
QList<MyClass> my_list;
```

Comment: did you include MyClass.h ?

Comment: Perhaps you installed the 32-bit x86 libraries instead of the x86_64? Perhaps you failed to place the libraries in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Does `MyClass` have any virtual methods you have forgotten to implement?  Or any static members that you have not declared in it's source file?

Comment: The issue was that I had a destructor defined in MyClass.  Once I commented that out, the code compiled.  I still have not tested it yet.  Does anyone know why that might cause such issues with QList?

Comment: You will have to show us what was in your destructor and how it was defined.

Answer (score 11):

According to the documentation:
**QList's value type must be an assignable data type.**

To qualify, a type must provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator. So your custom class should be implemented like this.

```
class MyClass
 {
 public:
     MyClass() {}
     MyClass(const MyClass &other);

     MyClass &operator=(const MyClass &other);

 private:
     //private data members
 };
```

Comment: +1'd this anyway because it solved my problem. As recommended in QList docs I store pointers instead to avoid the hassle.